# How to create social facebook web application using spring frame work

Tags: java, facebook, spring

I have an application which needs facebook integration using spring frame work.Can any one to help me how to create the application

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a Social module for FB integration Please take a look at

http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/ and
 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/wiki/Quick-Start